# Proof of Horn theorem with moment map

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry

Please look at this problem:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the space of $(n,n)$ hermitian matrix.

$\phi:\begin{align*} &\mathcal{H} \to \mathfrak{u}(n):=Lie(U(n)) \\&A \mapsto iA
\end{align*}$
identifies both spaces.

Let $T=\lbrace diag(\exp(i\tau_1),...,\exp(i\tau_n))\rbrace$ a maximal torus in $U(n)$, $\mathfrak{t}\simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ his Lie algebra.

$\textbf {1.}$
Let $A\in \mathcal{H}$, show that the moment map $\mu_T$ of the $T$-action on $\mathcal{O}_A:= Ad_{U(n)}A$ is $$\mu_T(B)=(B_{11},...,B_{nn}) \in \mathbb{R}^n\simeq \mathfrak{t}$$

*So we have to show that $\mu$ is T-equivariant, what is clear since T acts trivially on his Lie algebra
The second condition to be a moment map comes when computing $d<\mu\vert_B(\xi),\eta>$ and finding $\omega_B^{\mathfrak{u}_n}(\eta,\xi)=-Tr(B [\eta,\xi]).$
So i'm ok with this question now.*

$\textbf{2.}$
Show that the fixed points of this action are $\lbrace diag(\lambda_{\sigma(1)},...,\lambda_{\sigma(n)})\rbrace_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n}$ where the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $A$.

*Comes easily from a simple calculus, or with a bit of deeper knowledge on the adjoint action of maximum tori in compact groups.*

$\textbf{3.}$
Conclude that $(A_{11},...,A_{nn})$ lies in the convex span of $(\lambda_{\sigma(1)},...,\lambda_{\sigma(n)})\rbrace_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n}$

*I found in the Mc. Duff-Salamon's book (introduction on symplectic topology) something on it, but it's a strong theorem due to Atiyah-Guillemin-Sternberg, i think there is smth easier here... It's suppose to be an exercise!*

Thank you for whatever can help me!

Comment: It is just unwrapping of definitions. $\mu:\mathcal O_A\to \mathfrak{t}^*$ is a moment map for the $T$-action if for each $X\in\mathfrak t,$ the corresponding vector field on $\mathcal O_A$ is the hamiltoian vector field generated by the hamiltonian $\mu(X)$.

Comment: And so? I think i have to compute the derivative  $d<\mu(B),H>$ and show it gives something like $\omega(H,B)$, where $\omega$ is the symplectic form on $\mathcal{O}_A$. But it's not clear to me... And for the 2. and 3. ???

Comment: Ok Gil, i'm done with it. Please just some help for the 3?

Comment: I dont think there is an easy proof or shortcut. I didnt see the book you are using or the original proof of Horn, but my guess is that the exercise is meant to illustrate an application of the convexity theorem for the moment map of torus actions that you are quoting. When the convexity  theorem 1st came out (I think in the 80's) this exercise you are doing was the main propaganda for it, as an illustration of how an old result can be rejuvenated by illuminating it from a modern and higher point of view.

Comment: Yeah, i think you're right: it's the last year's exam of the course i'm following, and he probably changed the lecture a bit this year, omitting the convexity theorem! Cause the answer is obvious when you know that, and the question is "conclude" :) Anyway, thank you so much for your time, and sorry for my poor english!